# Can't apply permissions to VisualSVN Repo using Windows Authentication

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Here is my error message:

`Can't stat 'E:\Repositories\Test': Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete`

When trying to setup simple permissions on the repository I get this. I have given complete permissions to windows on this folder and still no luck!

I'd appreciate it if someone could help.

```
C:\Users\company_itsupport>icacls E:\
E:\ BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
    CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
    BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
    BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(AD)
    BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(IO)(WD)
    Everyone:(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\Users\company_itsupport>icacls E:\Repositories\
E:\Repositories\ NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE:(OI)(CI)(M)
                 CORP\company_itsupport:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 MUKS016\VisualSVN Server Admins:(OI)(CI)(M)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 CORP\MUKADIT:(OI)(CI)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\Users\company_itsupport>icacls E:\Repositories\Test
E:\Repositories\Test NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                      CORP\company_itsupport:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                      MUKS016\VisualSVN Server Admins:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                      CORP\MUKADIT:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Comment: Show us the result of these commands: "icacls E:\"

"icacls E:\Repositories\" and "icacls E:\Repositories\Test" and specify the user account under which you are logged on to Windows.

Comment: Ok bahrep, I've added the results as requested.

Comment: what's your user account and which AD groups it belongs to?

Comment: The account I'm using is CORP\company_itsupport and it's under MUKADIT.

Comment: Thank you, checking it now.

Comment: Do you work on visualsvn by any chance? Looking to purchase this if we can get win auth working correctly. I recently put through a request for evaluation license if you wanted to email etc.

Comment: @SVNVer I'm support engineer at VisualSVN, you can always contact us at support@visualsvn.com for technical queries and sales@visualsvn.com for sales ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is fixed in [VisualSVN Server 2.7.1](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v2.7.1).